# Can't center my slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried many things to center this slider. This includes  align="center" style="margin: 0 auto;" style="margin-right: 0 auto; margin-left: 0 auto;". All of these I have tried on the images and slider div too. I am not sure what what the problem is and any help would be very much appreciated. This is my first time posting so sorry if this is not the correct format. Below is the code I am having trouble with

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
  .fadeOut(1000)
  .next()
  .fadeIn(1000)
  .end()
  .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

```css
  #slideshow {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 720px;
    <!-- padding: 10px;
    --> box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  .ppt img {
    margin-left: -50%;
  }
  .ppt li {
    left: 50%;
  }
  #slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .clear {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="slideshow">
    <div>
      <img style="height:719;" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="height:719;" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="height:719;" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="height:719;" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="height:719;" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="height:719;" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="height:719;" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="height:719;" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="height:719;" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="height:719;" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to either set a width for the #slideshow, and set the margin as 0 auto, or set the div to be displayed as a block, along with the parent div. And set the parent div CSS to include text-align:center;.

Answer (score 0):

Your slideshow is centered. It's the images themselves that aren't centered. You can see evidence of this in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d99k0uab/). Centering the images would have more to do with your absolute positioning. You can use `left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0);` to center the images if that is the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, bunch of bad practices:

- Too many inline
- Don't need divs inside the slider. Try a list. Better
  code management.

Now to the problem. You can simply use

```
margin: auto;
```

for the #slideshow to horizontally centre it.